# How to speed up packet processing?

Tags: c#, dump

I am developing a call recording application in C#.net using `pcap.net` library. For packet capturing i am using Wireshark's `Dumpcap.exe`. And the packet files are creating in 5 second duration. To read each packet file what i have done is

```
   OfflinePacketDevice selectedDevice = new OfflinePacketDevice(filename);
            using (PacketCommunicator communicator =
           selectedDevice.Open(65536,                                  // portion of the packet to capture
                // 65536 guarantees that the whole packet will be captured on all the link layers
                               PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, // promiscuous mode
                               0))                                  // read timeout
            {

                communicator.ReceivePackets(0, DispatcherHandler);
```

In **DispatcherHandler** method i am processing each packets. **DispatcherHandler** call takes 0 seconds for each file .

I am getting  delay when prcessing the RTP packets packets in the **same** method..

To identify rtp packets I used **ordered dictionary** with key as `ipadrress+portnumber`. So I need to check whether this key exists in dictionary when each rtp packet comes. This task getting slower in processing each dump file.

```
if (objPortIPDict.Contains(ip.Source.ToString().Replace(".", "") + port))
{
 // here i write the rtp payload to a file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read a couple of strange things:

1) Why use `Contains` in [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

```
objPortIPDict.Contains(ip.Source.ToString().Replace(".", "") + port)
```

If `objPortIPDict` is a dictiaonary use [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

2) Derivates from first. If this is a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), its [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)has **O(1)** time of execution, so can not be affected by amount of data in dictionary itself.

Yes, it can be affected, if the amount of data becomse *so* big, that entire application becomes slower, but pick time will remain always constant in regard of current application state domain.

Comment: Exactly. It's O(1) because Dictionary uses hash codes, which are of course calculated as O(1). If the dictionary became so full that there were a lot of hash code collisions, it will become a lot slower than O(1) - but you are likely to run out of memory before that happens (at least for a 32 bit program).

Comment: **objPortIPDict** is an OrderedDictionary. In that keys inserting  are not numbers, its format like **"10.10.10.50,4000"**. Will it get slower when searching the key?

Comment: if you use ContainsKey, will not.

Comment: **Contains** Determines whether the System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary collection
         contains a specific key.